# Rails and capistrano installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, capistrano

Trying to configure rails and capistrano. Following gorails deploy guide for ubuntu 14.04. Running:

```
$ bundle --binstubs
Resolving dependencies...
Using...
...
Bundle complete! 24 Gemfile dependencies, 63 gems now installed.
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
```

and

```
$ cap install STAGES=production
```

produces this error

```
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- capistrano/cli (LoadError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/cap:3:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix this?

**Update**

My gemfile includes

```
gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'capistrano-rvm', github: "capistrano/rvm"
```

Comment: Do you have `gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'`, 
`gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.1.2'` and 
`gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.1.1'` in your Gemfile, as detailed in https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04#capistrano ?

Comment: Updated my question with gemfile fragment